# Integral solution of a linear program

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, integrality-gap

Consider the following linear program (LP)

$$
\begin{align*}
&\text{maximize }& &c^\prime x\\
&\text{subject to }& &Ax \leq b\\
& && 0\leq x_i \leq 1 \quad \forall i
\end{align*}
$$

We know that $b$ is integral, $A_{i,j} \in \{-1,0,1\}$. However, $A$ is not necessary totally unimodular. We also know that $c_i\in\{-1,1\}$ for all $i$. Does this condition force the solution of the LP to be integral? If so, how to prove it?

My intuition is that as each variable has a weight in the objective function, their optimal value has to be at the extreme, being either $0$ or $1$, so I expect an integral (binary) solution. Also, I have solved a number of instances, and all of them had integral solutions. Can anyone help me to prove or disprove this?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I see that you have created ([tag:integrality-gap]) tag. It might be useful to create also [tag-wiki or at least tag-excerpt](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/integrality-gap/info). It might help other users to use the tag correctly. Another reason is that the tags used on only one question are [automatically deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-pruning/info) after certain time [unless they have tag-wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is negative. Consider the following problem (corresponding to max-clique of $K_3$, the complete graph on three vertices):
$$\max x_1+x_2+x_2$$
$$ x_1 + x_2 \leq 1 $$
$$ x_1 + x_3 \leq 1 $$
$$ x_2 + x_3 \leq 1 $$
$$ 0 \leq x_i \leq 1 $$
The optimal solution is $x_i = 0.5$.

Comment: Thanks, in between I also realized that it does not hold. I need to see if I can make any further assumptions to make it hold. My A matrix is usually very sparse, might even be free of feedback loops.

Comment: Hi, I have posted a more specific description about the problem, see here:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093433/proof-of-binary-solution-of-a-linear-program-with-specific-structure